# How to convert date format coming in an ajax object?

Tags: javascript, ajax, date

I am getting `2018-06-10 00:29:04` this type of value in the key date. I just want to display date without time.

I want to have `2018-06-10` from `2018-06-10 00:29:04`.

Comment: `date.split(" ")[0]`

Comment: Could you elaborate on this or add code?

Comment: If you don't need to care about timezones, just do `date.split(" ")[0]`. Otherwise, in some scenarios, you may get the wrong day if the timezone is actually different.

Comment: @briosheje—the OP timestamp doesn't have a timezone, it should be parsed as local (assuming "otherwise" infers parsing).

Comment: @RobG What I meant is that it will NOT be parsed correctly if, somewhere, he is aware of the provided datetime's timezone.

Comment: Or `date.substr(0,10)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it's a fixed string that you're working with, as in you know it'll always be in that format, you can just truncate it like so:

```
var datetimestamp = "2018-06-10 00:29:04";

var dateTruncated = datetimestamp.slice(0, 10);
```

If it's not fixed, you can split on spaces like @Shubh mentioned in his comment and take the first array value.